# Windows Service or Web Service?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis-7, windows-services, asp.net-4.0

I have a public desktop site, a public mobile site, and a private intranet site on the same server. They are all written in C# (ASP.Net 4.0).

Each has their own code to process credit card payments. I would like to write a single application that handles credit card payments for all 3 sites. I want this application to only be accessible from these 3 local applications.

The only way I know how to do this is to create a web service and restrict traffic to the localhost.

Is there a better ("right") way to do this? Should I create a windows service instead?

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable solution to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general approach is sound.  However, I would not only rely on access being restricted to localhost.  A single misconfiguration at some later point in time would expose your payment web service.  Also, if the server is compromised, any process running on that local host would have unchecked access.

Always use authentication to secure your payment web service.

If you must deploy the authentication service on the same physical box as the front end websites, take particular care securing the payment service (e.g. if you are storing credit card numbers or PII related to the credit accounts e.g. name, address, ... ensure the database is correctly secured). If at all possible, place payment services in an additional layer separate from the public-facing (or co-worker facing) websites, protected by appropriate firewall rules.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think windows service would be good option if you have calling applications. As far as I know about WCF, we have option for NetTcpBinding and NetNamedPipeBinding which you might consider.

> **NetTcpBinding** - A secure and optimized binding suitable for cross-machine communication between WCF applications.
>
> **NetNamedPipeBinding** - A secure, reliable, optimized binding that is suitable for on-machine communication between WCF applications.